# slf4j apache tomcat eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, slf4j

hello I am currently building a java EE app with eclipse and I am trying to add slf4j to a servlet but nothing works as it should. I literally  put the logback.xml file in every directory of my project but and edited so the messages at the console are customized and not the defaults ones but the console output is always the same. Is it related that I use the apache-tomcat server ? Else can you tell me in which directory should I put the logback.xml file? Also should I add the log4j.properties file somewhere? In some tutorials it doesn't exists whereas on other it does.

here's the directory of my project
[image]

I have this servlet that writes to the logger:

```
    @WebServlet("/checkConnection")
public class checkConnection extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegBean.class);
    public checkConnection() {


        LOG.trace("Hello World!");
        LOG.debug("How are you today?");
        LOG.info("I am fine.");
        LOG.warn("I love programming.");
        LOG.error("I am programming.");

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

here's the logback.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.lordofthejars.foo" level="INFO" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <!-- Strictly speaking, the level attribute is not necessary since -->
  <!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default.       -->
  <root level="DEBUG">          
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  

</configuration>
```

and here is the console output:

```
Αυγ 12, 2014 4:23:56 ΜΜ servlets.checkConnection <init>
INFO: I am fine.
Αυγ 12, 2014 4:23:56 ΜΜ servlets.checkConnection <init>
WARNING: I love programming.
Αυγ 12, 2014 4:23:56 ΜΜ servlets.checkConnection <init>
SEVERE: I am programming.
```

According to the configuration file the output shouldn't include the date, right? So I think that logger hasn't identified the configuration file.

Comment: Should go in the root of the classpath. Doesn't look like you're using maven structure (where it would go in `src/main/resource`), so just put it in the default package `src` directly (i.e. src/logback.xml). log4j.properties should be in root of classpath (unless configured differently)

Comment: it doesn't work I i'll upload details to be sure that everything else is correct

Comment: Of course! Check the updated question if you want!